# Удалить запись из бд

Tags: php

У меня есть таблица. В ней выводится все данные из бд. У меня есть кнопка по удалению этой записи из дб. Но она не работает, помогите пожалуйста ребята.

```html
<?php
 require 'config.php';
 if(empty($_SESSION['name']))
  header('Location: login.php');
  

  $sql="select * from admin_blog order by id desc";
  $data=$connect->prepare($sql);
  $data->execute();
  $allpost=$data->fetchAll();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Панель управления</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
 
   <?php
    if(isset($errMsg)){
     echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:17px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
    }
   ?>
   <div style="background-color:#006D9C; color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px;"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></div>
   
    

    
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
 <th scope="col" class="ranke">Фото</th>
      <th scope="col" class="ranke">Название</th>
      <th scope="col">Описание</th>
      <th scope="col" class="hidden-2">Текст</th>
      <th scope="col" class="hidden">Категория</th>
   <th scope="col" class="hidden">Добавить</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
   if($allpost){
   foreach($allpost as $rows){ ?>
    <tr>

 <form method="post">
 <td class="img_td"> <img class="add-img" src="<?php echo $rows['img'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="img" value="<?php echo $rows['img'];?>"></td>
      <td class="hidden-2"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['blog_title'];?>" name="title"></td>
 
      <td class="hidden">  <textarea name="description" cols="25" rows="10"><?php echo $rows['description'];?></textarea></td>
   <td class="hidden"> <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $rows['content'];?></textarea></td>
   <td class="hidden"><input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $rows['category'];?>"></td>
   <td>
   <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn" value="Удалить статью">
   </td>
   
   </form>
    </tr>
 <?php   
  }
   }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

  
  if (isset($_GET['id'])){
 
 

  $sql = "DELETE FROM admin_blog WHERE id=:id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->execute();
  

   }

 }
?>

 <a href="logout.php">Выйти</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы `id` пытаетесь из массива `$_GET` получить, а надо `$_POST`

Comment: Оборачивать `td` в тег `form` - __невалидно__. Браузер изменит разметку и форм у вас будет меньше чем вы ожидаете.